# Other thread position

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I have a deadlock in my code and I want to debug it. 
Due to some reasons, I can't reconstruct it here. The problem reconstructed only at my customers.

My idea is to poll the threads once an hour and check whether they are stuck in the problematic code. I know that there is an option to print the current line of code with `__line__` and `__file__`. Can i do it to another thread?

For example in my case - I want that my thread will sample the other threads and print their current line of code.

Edit - My platform is RHEL 5.6 and the code is in C++.

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: `__line__` and `__file__` are just literals. You can input them in a string and "send" this string to the other thread.

Comment: @Hayt The OP does not know where the deadlock happens. Otherwise the OP would not put a question.

Comment: Deadlock detection is not so easy, sometimes it implies S.O. help. Check for a deadlock from the internal application itself it could be no possible. Maybe you could construct an external tool which interacts with your application, exploiting some S.O. api. Or maybe attach the debug-program on execution code when the code stuck. Actually I'm thinking about watchdog

Comment: @Serge The question was not about finding the deadlock but whether to print line and file in another thread. But I also misunderstood. He want a mechanism to check programatically in which part of the code another thread is.

Comment: @Hayt unless we know the platform there is nothing to do with `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`

Comment: LINE and FILE should be standard preprocessor macros though. They should not be platform dependend.

Comment: @GMichael my platform is RHEL 5.6.

Comment: in addition to @GMichael answer, if you ship your app with stripped off debug info then rebuild the app with debug info included, then strip the debug info off from a copy and ship that copy to a client. Then you could convert hexadecimal addresses to files/line-numbers with `addr2line -e <file> <addr>` utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe has some quirks but here is an approach to this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define TRACK t.line = __LINE__; t.file=__FILE__;
struct Track
{
    int line;    
    std::string file;
};

int main()
{
  Track t;
  TRACK int i = 0;
  std::cout << t.file;
}
```

You can add "TRACK" before each statement and access the Track object from another thread to print out where the tracking thread is.

Comment: How that could help to identify the deadlock in multi-threaded server application? Even if you succeed to put your TRACK macro into every line of the source code and also you add a debug output at every other line you will change the timings drastically (apart from `std::cout <<` is not thread-safe, I believe) so the deadlock may not even happen at all.

Comment: He is not asking to identify the deadlock. He is asking for a way to figure out at what position the other thread is.

Comment: Don't be formal. He does not need that. He need to find a deadlock

Comment: Yes I know. but without posting code we cannot help much there. So he wants to find it himself using a way to "visualize" the thread flow (like logging output which would probably be a smarter way). Finding the deadlock would be the ideal solution though you are right in that.

Comment: Without *knowing platform* we cant help him. Posting the code would not help in this case. Do you think his app is 20 lines length?

Comment: I'm working in a big product. It have millions of lines of code. Even my suspected code may be hundreds of lines. There are also many kinds of locks like semaphores, mutexes and condition variables.
My platform is Redhat 5.6.

Comment: as an alternative to my solution you could add logging to the threads and add log messages at certain points with prefixing the thread ID or something. this is probably better because you don't introduce another thread just to log things.

Comment: Hi, i guess that there is no other option but to throw mud at the code :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `pstack` when I suspect this. It does not require code changes and shows state of all the threads in the application. I run `pstack` several times one after another and compare the results.

Comment: Thanks! but the problem didn't reproduced in our lab. Only at some of our customers.
I can't run pstack at the customer's environment. He would never allow me to do debugging stuff at his servers.

Comment: @user296589 You can ask them to run the application and just give you the log files. `pstack` does not interfere with the application code and does not expose any customer data. In addition, some customers have what we call 'production lab' when the same processing is done but without access to the real data. You can try this approach in their production lab if exists.

Comment: @user296589 as the customer is fine to run your app you ship in a binary form (am I correct?) he should have nothing against the statistics collection module that runs periodically and even open-sourced. what do you think?

Comment: Strangely, i tried to use pstack in a lab machine. It dumped only 11 threads, while there are hundreds of threads. Non on them was the threads that are getting stuck. Maybe there is a limit on the threads number of their depth (Like child-threads and so on).

Comment: It might be a `pstack` problem. You can emulate `pstack` with `gdb`: `gdb -batch -p <PID> -x <FILE>` where the <FILE> contains the following command: `thread apply all bt`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to follow a strategy like that:

- Identify what exactly threads produce a deadlock
- Identify last working code of those threads
- Identify why the deadlock between them occurs.

Then, it depends on thread library you use and platform. Let's assume pthreads + linux pc.

- Here you can print pthread_self() and a timestamp and then analyze thich one has stucked. This will change timings so, that the deadlock might not occurre then. In this case you should think how to optimize this to do not affect to the reproducibility (i.e. integrate the output or collect it internally and then read via debugger or whatever)
- When you have identified the suspects, go to their implementations and search the place where they can stuck to identify the object of the deadlock.
- When you know the threads and the objects, you should analyze how the object is used by them in dynamic. Then mapping this dynamic behavior to the properties of the object you will get know why this happens.

Comment: Thanks you for you ideas. I already did what you said. Most of them already exists in our code. I have the problematic function and which threads are stuck. But there are many kinds of mutexes inside it along with thousands of code lines that i don't know. I just need a clean way to print the threads location in a specific time stamp.